# Function not saving data to file onDestroy() Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I do the following function in my main activity

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
 SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().saveChanges(this);  
}
```

When Android later call the method function saveChanges() when I close the Application I get the "SaveChanges" outprint but not the last print "After Saving" meaning that its not executing the whole function and I'm not getting any outPrints on the catch exceptions lines either. Do you know why? I'm new to android and do not understand if you could run this code onDestroy(). =)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;

public class SimpleBookManager implements BookManager, java.io.Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    private static SimpleBookManager ref;       


    public void saveChanges(Context context){
        try{
            System.out.println("SaveChanges");
            FileOutputStream f_out = context.openFileOutput("myobject.data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            // Write object with ObjectOutputStream
            ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new    ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
        // Write object out to disk
        obj_out.writeObject(allBooks);
        System.out.println("After Saving");

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No file found saveChanges");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException in SaveChanges");
    }   
}




public void loadBooks(Context context){
    try{
    // Read from disk using FileInputStream
        FileInputStream f_in = context.openFileInput("myobject.data");

    // Read object using ObjectInputStream
    ObjectInputStream obj_in =  new ObjectInputStream (f_in);

    // Read an object
    Object obj = obj_in.readObject();
    //System.out.println(obj);
    if (obj instanceof ArrayList<?>)
    {
        allBooks = (ArrayList<Book>) obj;

        System.out.println("Worked");
        System.out.println(allBooks);

    }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No file found LoadBooks");
    } catch (IOException e) {


    System.out.println("IOException in loadBooks");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFound in loadBooks");
    }

}

  public static SimpleBookManager getSimpleBookManager()
  {
    if (ref == null){
        ref = new SimpleBookManager();
    }

    return ref;
  }
public SimpleBookManager(){
    Book book1 = createBook();
    book1.setAuthor("RandomBookAuthor");
    book1.setCourse("Kunskap");
    book1.setPrice(199);
    book1.setTitle("Some Random Title");
    book1.setIsbn("9780590353403");
}
```

}

I also get IOException when doing this onCreate() in main, so something is really fishy about my load and save functions.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().loadBooks(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_main);
}
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

I have added the permission to the manifest to write to storage in the last lines of the manifest below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.av.BookApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

        >
        <activity
            android:name=".BookApp"
            android:label="@string/title_bookapp"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <activity
        android:name=".AddBookActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="edu.chalmers.BookApp" />
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="edu.chalmers.BookApp" />
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".EditBookActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="edu.chalmers.BookApp" />
    </activity>

    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

---

**Edit**

After I followed the advice below I now get a IOException in saveChanges()

And I do set the data correct like this (In SimpleBookManager)

```
public SimpleBookManager(){
Book book1 = createBook();
    book1.setAuthor("RandomBookAuthor");
    book1.setCourse("Kunskap");
    book1.setPrice(199);
    book1.setTitle("Some Random Title");
    book1.setIsbn("9780590353403");
}
```

Comment: Are you setting data to `allBooks` arraylist properly?

Comment: I don't see the problem with your code,  1st off add rows: `Toast.makeText(this, "The Service was destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  stopSelf();` . You can add to Toast everything what u want to detect the problem (in case if logs don't help u)

Comment: Why wait until the activities are destroyed? Why not save the data as soon as changes are made?

Answer (score 0):

i think you save the data in onResume meothd it's guarantee the system will make the action before kill the process

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your `onCreate()` method

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_main);
    SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().loadBooks(this);
 }
```

and Override `onStop()` method and don't override `onDestroy` method:

```
 @Override
 public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().saveChanges(this);  
 }
```